# How to Call a fragment of activity1 from a fragment of activity2

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 activity, On activity1 i add 2 fragment and activity2 so.How to Call a fragment of activity1 from a fragment of activity2.
I use  fragmentTransaction.commit() to call but is error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: MainActivity cannot be cast to   SignInWithEmailFragment$OnSignInWithEmailFragmentListener
```

[image]

Comment: show your both activity code

Comment: This is fragment i use to call from activity2

Comment: you are casting MainActivity to Fragment

Comment: thank for answer, It is like facebook application, i want fragment Logout(activity1) from fragment2 (activity2).

Comment: Start activity one and pass a variable that tells it that you logged out and then open the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> package life.youlook.youlooklife.ui.more;
>
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.AdapterView;
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.widget.ListView;
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> import life.youlook.youlooklife.R;
> import life.youlook.youlooklife.model.AllThing;
> import life.youlook.youlooklife.model.More;
> import life.youlook.youlooklife.services.GetYourInterestedAsyncTask;
> import life.youlook.youlooklife.ui.BaseContainerFragment;
> import life.youlook.youlooklife.ui.BaseFragment;
> import life.youlook.youlooklife.ui.mainscreen.MainActivity;
> import life.youlook.youlooklife.ui.mainscreen.OnChangeActionbarListener;
> import life.youlook.youlooklife.ui.startscreen.SignInWithEmailFragment;
>
> /**
>  * Created by Welcome on 9/1/2015.
>  */
> public class MoreFragment extends BaseFragment implements GetYourInterestedAsyncTask.OnGetYourInterestedListener
>         , MainActivity.OnChangeActionbarFromActivity{
>     ArrayList<More> arrayMore;
>     MoreAdapter moreAdapter;
>     ListView lvMore;
>     Button btnCreateTopic;
>     private OnChangeActionbarListener onChangeActionbarListener;
>
>
>
>     @Override
>     public void init() {
>         onChangeActionbarListener = (OnChangeActionbarListener) getActivity();
>         lvMore = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_more_lvMore);
>         btnCreateTopic =(Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_more_btnCreateTopic);
>         arrayMore = new ArrayList<>();
>         moreAdapter = new MoreAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.row_more, arrayMore,this,"More");
>         lvMore.setAdapter(moreAdapter);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void setValue() {
>         arrayMore.add(new More(R.drawable.more_update, getResources().getString(R.string.more_update)));
>         arrayMore.add(new More(R.drawable.more_notifications, getResources().getString(R.string.more_notification)));
>         arrayMore.add(new More("SUPPORT"));
>         arrayMore.add(new More(R.drawable.more_report, getResources().getString(R.string.more_report)));
>         arrayMore.add(new More(R.drawable.more_term, getResources().getString(R.string.more_term)));
>         arrayMore.add(new More(R.drawable.more_privace, getResources().getString(R.string.more_privace)));
>         arrayMore.add(new More(R.drawable.more_language, getResources().getString(R.string.more_language)));
>         arrayMore.add(new More(R.drawable.more_about, getResources().getString(R.string.more_about)));
>         arrayMore.add(new More(R.drawable.more_logout, getResources().getString(R.string.more_logout)));
>
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public int getLayoutId() {
>         return R.layout.fragment_more;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void setEvent() {
>         onChangeActionbarListener.changeTitle(getTitle(), this);
>         btnCreateTopic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>
>             }
>         });
>         lvMore.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
>                 if(arrayMore.get(position).getmText().equals("Log Out")){
>                     SignInWithEmailFragment email = new SignInWithEmailFragment();
>                             ((BaseContainerFragment) MoreFragment.this.getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(email, false);
>
>                 }
>             }
>         });
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public String getTitle() {
>         return "Collection";
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void OnGetYourInterestedFinish(ArrayList<AllThing> arrayAll) {
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
ProfileFragment mProfileFragment = new ProfileFragment(); 
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();  
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
.beginTransaction();  
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,  
mProfileFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(MyProfileFragment.class
.getName());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: You need to create a FragmentManager to add your fragment in a FragmentActivity (or call another FragmentActivity via an Intent and add your fragment on it).